# Mongodb - query for elements in a list of tags combining $all and $nin

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collections with records that looks something like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55024bb1f36088d8ce7a79e8"),
"date_taken" : ISODate("2015-01-13T13:50:31.000Z"),
"db_filename" : "2015-01-13 13.50.31.jpg",
"db_original_height" : 3264,
"db_latitude" : -44.66694444444444,
"db_tags" : [ 
    "January", 
    "2015", 
    "Tuesday", 
    "GT-I9300", 
    "SAMSUNG", 
    "New Zealand/Aotearoa", 
    "Southland", 
    "Afternoon", 
    "Medium file"
],
"db_original_path" : "/Users/hingem/my_image_store/imgs/2015-01-13 13.50.31.jpg",
"db_date_taken" : ISODate("2015-01-13T13:50:31.000Z"),
"db_ImageUniqueID" : "ZDFI02\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000\u0000",
"db_thumb_path" : "/Users/hingem/thumbs/imgs/2015-01-13 13.50.31_tm.jpg",
"db_flash_fired" : 0,
"db_has_exif" : true,
"db_size" : 3224612,
"db_model" : "GT-I9300",
"db_location" : true,
"db_large_path" : "/Users/hingem/thumbs/imgs/2015-01-13 13.50.31_lg.jpg",
"db_longitude" : 167.9216666666667,
"db_make" : "SAMSUNG",
"db_medium_path" : "/Users/hingem/thumbs/imgs/2015-01-13 13.50.31_md.jpg",
"db_original_width" : 2448,
"db_orientation" : 1,
"db_address" : "Milford Foreshore Walk, Milford Sound, Southland, New Zealand/Aotearoa",
"db_country" : "New Zealand/Aotearoa",
"db_state" : "Southland",
"db_road" : null
```

}

the important bit is the db_tags field which is a list of tags. I want to query for all records that include or exclude certain tags. I have thin working:

```
db.images.find({'db_tags': 
{'$all': ['Medium file', '2015']}
})
```

which returns all records containing both tags. How do I add a $nin clause to that query?? so in psudo code:

give me all records where db_tag contains 'Medium file' and '2015' but where db_tags does not contain 'January'

Comment: Just add the condition to the same subdocument: {'db_tags': {'$all': ['Medium file', '2015'],$nin:["January"]} }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine multiple query operators, using ',' to separate them which is equivalent to an "and".

```
db.images.find( {'db_tags': {'$all': ['Medium file', '2015'],$nin:["January"]} })
```

Comment: Yup... That was it... Although the $nin keyword has to be in quotes. Thanks! So simple... I wanted it to be much more complex